# Getting arguments from URL

Tags: uri

How do I get arguments from the URL? in other words, what is the equivalent of the `arg()` function of Drupal 7 and previous versions?

Comment: I'm the maintainer for the [D7 Ported Functions for D8/9](https://www.drupal.org/project/d7d8) module, which seeks to port Drupal 7 functions into drupal 8/9 to make development easier. We have an `arg()` drop-in replacement for Drupal 8/9. It's `d7d8_arg()`.

Answer (score 17):

As reported in the [arg() is deprecated and will be removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705) change record, the Drupal 8 (procedural) equivalent of `arg()` is the following one.

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
```

As the change record makes notice, not all the times that is the correct code to use. Depending from the context, you should use code similar to the following one.

- Check if a path is for an administrative page

  ```
  if (\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {
    // Your code.
  }
  ```
- Add CSS or JavaScript conditionally, basing on the page being visited

  ```
  function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'my.route') {
      $attachments ['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_library'; // you'll need to define in mymodule.libraries.yml
    }
  }
  ```
- Load the currently viewed node

  ```
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  ```

Notice that in the first and last case, in Drupal 7 you should not use `arg()`, but respectively `path_is_admin()` and `menu_get_object()`. The typical *beginner-Drupal-developer* error is using `arg()` also in those cases.

Answer (score 5):

arg() is deprecated in drupal 8, however we can get values like arg() function does in drupal 7 & 6 by mentioned

```
$path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
$arg  = explode('/',$path);
print_r($arg); exit();
```

The output would be parameters in url except basepath or (baseurl),

```
Array
(
   [0] => 
   [1] => node
   [2] => add
)
```