# How can I understand when a node is being edited or viewed?

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to add a class to the body to distinguish the node's view page from the edit page.

In classy you have `'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class`. I'd like to add `page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class ~ '-edit'` if we're on the edit page, but I can't figure out what that `if` statement would have in its condition.

Which code should I use to add that class only when a node is being edited?

Comment: I think what you may want to do is handle this in the `.theme` file and add logic to pass additional classes in based on the path. See this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/208617/57

Comment: Beautiful! I think that's an answer though? It's appearing it will solve my question quite well.

Comment: Alright, I will post it as an answer. Some people don't want to write anything in the .theme file, which is why I asked first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you'd want to look at parts of the url. The easiest way to do that would be passing in additional classes from a preprocess function in the .theme file, and by looking at the URL path:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$path_args = explode('/', $current_path);

if ($path_args[0] == 'node' && $path_args[2] == 'edit') {
  // add classes
}
```

This would be similar to using the `arg()` function from previous versions.

Comment: Worked great! Made a small edit in practice, I cliped off the first char of $current_path, it's a `/`, and if you don't $path_args[0] was an empty string. Also made sure that the 0 and 2 index existed so I don't get an error on pages that don't have 3 args.

Comment: In practice I also decided to set a var `$variables['is_node_edit']`, might come in handy more than once, and then I'm still setting all of my classes in the twig file.

Comment: Nevermind the slice - first you'd have to split the var by '/' then use slice against it. It's a bit too much for a twig template in my opinion.

Comment: Is the node.html.twig template used when a node is being edited? I would think it is not used when a node is edited.

Comment: I needed the class on the body tag so I could style the page title, so node.html.twig wasn't what I needed. 

On the edit page it doesn't use the node template at all, it uses form.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

The [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x) template is just used when the a node is displayed, as the documentation itself says. (Emphasis is mine.) So you don't have any need of using a `if` statement to distinguish the view case from the edit case, since the template files used are two different ones.

> Default theme implementation **to display** a node.

The template used when a node is being edited is a different one. In the comments in the [`theme_get_suggestions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/8.2.x) function, you can see which template files are suggested for a path like node/1/edit.

- page__node
- page__node__%
- page__node__1
- page__node__edit

The last one is more specific for your case, since you need to use it when a node is being edited, independently from the node ID.

If you just need to add a CSS class when a node is being edited, you can take the code in [`seven_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21seven%21seven.theme/function/seven_preprocess_html/8.2.x) as guide.

```
  $path_args = explode('/', \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo());
  if ($suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page', '-')) {
    foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) {
      if ($suggestion === 'page-node-edit' || strpos($suggestion, 'page-node-add') !== FALSE) {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $the_class_you_want_to_add;
      }
    }
  }
```

That code adds a CSS class when a node is created or edited; if you just need to add a CSS class when an existing node is edited, you can simplify the code.

```
  $path_args = explode('/', \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo());
  if ($suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page', '-')) {
    foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) {
      if ($suggestion === 'page-node-edit') {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $the_class_you_want_to_add;
      }
    }
  }
```