# Redirect to 404 page, if the path alias doesn't exist

Tags: 8, path-aliases, redirection

I am developing a multilingual site in Drupal 8. I added content in Turkish and I didn't create any translation for that node.
I managed to redirect user to the path alias. For example, when users visit https://example.com/tr/node/123, they are redirected to https://example.com/tr/custom-node-in-turkish.

When users visit https://example.com/node/123 or https://example.com/ar/node/123, they should be redirected to the 404 page.

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Maybe you can implement something like this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208608/getting-arguments-from-url to check if the language is present or not

Answer (score 0):

You could add the redirect to the .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 /ar/node/123 /page-not-found
```

Comment: What about for those who are not using Apache, like site running on Nginx, IIS, etc?

Answer (score 0):

How did you managed to redirect users to the page alias? Maybe you could use:

```
throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
```